# Exponential scaling of an axis in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, exponential

A logarithmic scale is useful if you care more about the variations in data for small numbers than those for large numbers. An exponential scale should be useful for the opposite use case—i.e., when smaller variations in larger numbers are important.

Gnuplot has builtin support for scaling the axes logarithmically. Does it have support for exponential scaling? If so, what is the syntax to use that? If not, what is there an elegant workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no builtin support for exponential scaling. You can plot the graph `using (exp($1)):2`, though.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. (I think you also need parentheses for it to even run, like this: `(exp($1)):2`.) All my data disappears of the plot. It would be nice to have the tics scaled as well, to simulate native support for it.

Comment: @Kazark: You are right. You can adjust the ticks like this: `set ytics('0' 1, '43' 1e43); plot '< seq 1 100' using 0:(exp($1))`